# What counts as transactions for HERE Map API's turn-by-turn and voice instructions?

Tags: here-api

I know that 1 transaction is 15 map tile requests, but what about turn-by-turn navigation? When that is enabled, is it incurring a transaction every time the 3rd-person-view map is updated? Also, what about voice? Is it a transaction every time a voice instruction is spoken?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction based billing is exclusively for the "Basic" to "Premium" plans, that include the Starter MobileSDK. And the StarterSDK is not having turn by turn voice guidance capabilities.

Turn by turn voice guidance is included in the HERE Premium SDK that you can get via a custom plan. This is normally not billed via transactions (since many features have offline capabilities there and don't do any network transactions).

Comment: So in the custom plan, it's a flat rate for unlimited usage?

Comment: The custom plans are mainly per device for the premium SDK, but since the plans are "custom" this is something HERE Sales will negotiate.